# How to select checkbox manually in wpf when toggle button exist?

Tags: wpf

When I clicked toggle button it selects each and every checkbox. When
I click the toggle button again, it will uncheck every checkbox.

If I clicked individual checkbox, it selects all checkbox.
Is it possible to select manually individual checkbox without clicking toggle button?

```xaml
<CheckBox Uid="checkbox1" Name="checkbox1" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_UnChecked" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=button,Path=IsChecked}">
    <Image Source="{Binding Path=UriSource}" Stretch="Fill" Width="100" Height="120" />
</CheckBox>    
<ToggleButton x:Name="button" Content="Select/Unselect" Click="ToggleButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,545,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Height="57" RenderTransformOrigin="0.986,1.365" />
```

Comment: You mention *"every checkbox"* and *"individual checkbox"* but your code only shows one checkbox. I feel like you are missing some parts of a [mcve].

Comment: when run the program, i'm getting 10 checkboxs for 10 images. if images increases checkbox also increases dynamically. -manfred-radlwimmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with the help of following code

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Name="checkbox1"
                  Content="Checkbox 1"
                  Margin="5"
                  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=button,Path=IsChecked,Mode=OneWay}"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox Name="checkbox2"
                  Content="Checkbox 2"
                  Margin="5"
                  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=button,Path=IsChecked,Mode=OneWay}"></CheckBox>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="button"
                      Content="Select/Unselect"
                      Width="Auto"
                      Height="25"
                      Margin="5"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </StackPanel>
```

You need to set **binding mode** of check boxes to **OneWay** as shown in above code

Comment: Thank you. i added mode=OneWay

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding!!